# SQL select from table 1 IF table2anme.value=1

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables,

(Table test_forms) one table with column:

id, etc

(Table test_subrecords) other table with columns:

id, record, element,    title,  name,   type,   value

I need a SQL code to:

select from (Table test_forms) ID=67 (number)

AND

select from (Table test_subrecords) Title= "N.º de anos de residência no concelho"  (text)

AND

select from (Table test_subrecords) Value= "Masculino"  (text)

I have this code but returns no value...

```
SELECT `test_forms`.`id`, `test_subrecords`.`title`, `test_subrecords`.`value`
```

FROM `test_forms`, `test_subrecords`
WHERE `test_forms`.`id` = '67' AND `test_subrecords`.`title` = 'N.º de anos de residência no concelho' AND `test_subrecords`.`value` = 'Masculino';

Tx in advance

Comment: What does `IF table2.name.value=1` mean? That's a table, I would assume with more than one record. Which record from `table2` would be the one to check for `name.value = 1`? Can you share some sample data and desired results to help with the clarity?

Comment: Fyi, *I need...* is NOT a question.

Comment: This is to make some graphs with forms data

SELECT value, record 
FROM `#__subrecords` 
WHERE `title` LIKE 'test' 

This is working, but I have a lot of same fields names so I have to choose the right form. The form number is on other table #__forms, and the ID = 1

I want to select vlue and recird from table #__subrecords but only if in table #__forms the ID = 1

Tx in advance

Comment: Please update the question with these details, and please provide sample data. It's very difficult to understand your data without seeing it. My guess is that a correlated subquery is likely a solution, butit's just a guess as there just isnt' enough information here to write sql for you.

Comment: 'code'SELECT value, record 
FROM `#__subrecords` 
WHERE `title` LIKE 'residencia' 

union

SELECT name, id
FROM `#__forms` 
WHERE `id` LIKE '67'

order by record desc limit 100

Comment: the union is not good. I just need the values from table subrecords IF forms ID = 67 Tx in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is to make some graphs with forms data.<br> 
SELECT value, record FROM #__subrecords WHERE title LIKE 'test' <br> 
This is working, but I have a lot of same fields names so I have to choose the right form. <br> 
The form number is on other table #__forms, and the ID = 1 <br> 
I need to select column "value" and column "record" from table "#__subrecords" but only if in table "#__forms" the column "ID" = 1 as the value "1" <br> 
Something like this:<br> 
SELECT value, record FROM #__subrecords WHERE title LIKE 'test' IF #__forms ID=1<br> 
Tx in advance<br>

Answer (score 0):

Your query is OK apart from the join, which should work even if it is effectively a cross join. See below schema on sql-server, should work on most rdbms:

> ```
> create Table test_forms(id int);
> insert into test_forms values(67),(68);
>
> create Table test_subrecords(
> id int , record int , element int , 
> title varchar(100), name varchar(100),
> type varchar(100), value varchar(100));
>
> insert into test_subrecords 
> (id,title,value) values
> (67,'N.º de anos de residência no concelho','Masculino'),
> (67,'other value for title','Masculino'),
> (68,'N.º de anos de residência no concelho','Masculino');
>
> SELECT test_forms.id, test_subrecords.title, test_subrecords.value 
> FROM test_forms join test_subrecords on test_forms.id = test_subrecords.id
> WHERE test_forms.id = '67' 
> AND test_subrecords.title = 'N.º de anos de residência no concelho' 
> AND test_subrecords.value = 'Masculino';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title                                   | value    
> -: | :-------------------------------------- | :--------
> 67 | N.º de anos de residência no concelho | Masculino
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf28ff8e98cc42c90336ee2af7343000)*